# Get current tab html element on button click in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to add a button to the chrome extension and get the html information of the current page when this button is clicked.

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "get current html of page ",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "my first extension",

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

`popup.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
     target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ["parse_page.js"],
  });
});
```

`parse_page.js`

```
var ps1 = document.getElementsByClassName('s1wl91l5-4 cBVHJG')[0].innerHTML;  
window.alert(ps1);
```

When chrome extension is clicked in my current application, the application works. I want to run when the button is clicked. can you help me

Comment: What do you mean by "get the html information of the current page". Do you want to query the HTML by a CSS selector?

Comment: I'll get what's between the html tags of the current page. i can do this. my problem is to do it with button

Answer (score 0):

in file `popup.html` change string `"popup.js"` to `"parse_page.js"`
and remove

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
     target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ["parse_page.js"],
  });
```

in file `background.js`

Comment: I did what you said but no results. I want to add a button and I want to get information when this button is clicked

Comment: add a button in the html?

Comment: I did this but I don't know what to write as a function or use the button